# Python - search and replace vowels in string

Tags: python

i need to write code in Python that will be able to detect if a certain character in a string is there and replace it with another character of my choice. for example, i need to replace all vowels in a string with "$&@", so after the string "hello world" goes through the code, it will turn into "h$&@ll$&@ w$&@rld". Does anybody know how to do this using very basic python and not really any pre existing functions?
thank you

Comment: the "no pre existing functions" bit sounds like homework.

Comment: `print(''.join((c, '$&@')[c.lower() in 'aeiou'] for c in 'hello world'))`. And now go and explain this to your teacher.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "pre existing functions"?

Answer (score 2):

without using `re` or `str.replace`:

```
 def trans(s):
    rpl = "$&@"
    res = ""
    for letter in s: # loop over the string s 
        if letter in {"a","e","i","o","u","A","E","I","O","U"}: # if any letter in vowels
            res+= rpl # add replacement substring
        else:
            res+= letter # else just add the letter
    return  res
```

To just output the word we could remove the concatenation:

```
import sys
def trans(s,rpl):
    for letter in s: # loop over the string s
        if letter in {"a","e","i","o","u","A","E","I","O","U"}: # if any letter in vowels
           sys.stdout.write(rpl)
        else:
            sys.stdout.write(letter)
(trans("hello world","$&@"))
```

Comment: @RickTeachey, if just the output is needed we could remove a lot of the code.

Answer (score 1):

Use [re](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) module:

```
import re
string = "Hello world"
print(re.sub("a|e|i|o|u", "xx", string))
```

this will print

```
>>> Hxxllxx wxxrld
```

Answer (score 1):

First method

```
>>> "".join(map(lambda x: '$&@' if x in "aeiou" else x, "hello world"))
'h$&@ll$&@ w$&@rld'
```

Second method

```
>>> s = "hello world"
>>> for ch in s:
...     if ch in "aeiou":
...             s = s.replace(ch,'$&@')
... 
>>> s
'h$&@ll$&@ w$&@rld
```

Comment: @RickTeachey, last time I looked str.replace was a function/method

Comment: in a way so are `for`, `if`, `in`, `=`, `()`, `''`, `,`, `.` and `:`. it wasn't a very good question.

Answer (score 0):

Through `re.sub`,

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'[aeiou]', r'$&@', "hello world")
'h$&@ll$&@ w$&@rld'
```

Comment: That looks a lot like a pre-existing function to me.

Comment: Wasn't my downvote, but the OP was specifically looking for a way which didn't involve "really any pre existing functions?".